# The given key was not present in the dictionary. VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to debug an issue I didnt create and I'm getting the generic error "The given key was not present in the dictionary." Here is the code:

```
   Dim myInfo As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

                        For i As Integer = 0 To Region.GetRegionCount - 1
                            myInfo.Add(i, Server.HtmlEncode(ContentItem.Properties("StoreInfoRegion" & i).Value.ToString))
                        Next

                        Session(SESSION_INFO) = myInfo
```

When I step thru it the error occurs on the call to "Add", I guess Im confused because it's adding a key not trying to access one.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty big line of code. The error could be when accessing Properties

Comment: yes, it looks like whatever `ContentItem.Properties` is doing is accessing a dictionary.

Comment: My confusion is it is just trying to add the key, not read from it.

Comment: @chromeOne7 ContentItem.Properties is reading from a key.

Answer (score 3):

You have a pretty big line of code, split it up into it's pieces and you might find where the problem is exactly.

Instead of

```
myInfo.Add(i, Server.HtmlEncode(ContentItem.Properties("StoreInfoRegion" & i).Value.ToString))
```

Have

```
Dim propertyValue As String
propertyValue = ContentItem.Properties("StoreInfoRegion" & i).Value.ToString
propertyValue = Server.HtmlEncode(propertyValue)
myInfo.Add(i, propertyValue)
```

With this change, I'm pretty sure that you will see the error on the 2nd line where you fetch the value of Properties. This mean you do not have a value for "StoreInfoRegion" & i

You could do

```
If ContentItem.Properties.ContainsKey("StoreInfoRegion" & i) Then
    Dim propertyValue As String
    propertyValue = ContentItem.Properties("StoreInfoRegion" & i).Value.ToString
    propertyValue = Server.HtmlEncode(propertyValue)
    myInfo.Add(i, propertyValue)
End If
```

But I think you should first understand why there are no value for that key first.

Comment: It does fail on that line, how can I check this before ever accessing the property? I'm a C# guy so I'm new to VB.NET

Comment: Assuming `ContentItem.Properties` is a dictionary you can add this line before calling myInfo.Add(): `If Not ContentItem.Properties.ContainsKey("StoreInfoRegion" & i) Then Continue For`

Comment: thanks, this however errors, there isn't a member called ContainsKey it's a third party product search engine.